# ValueError: Cannot convert *.csv stuff* to excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am batch-coverting .csv files to .xlsx files using a quick python script:

```
import csv
import glob
import openpyxl
import os

for csv_file in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    with open(csv_file, 'rU') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
            for c, val in enumerate(reader, start=1):
                ws.cell(row=r,column=c).value = val
    wb.save(os.path.splitext(csv_file)[0] + '.xlsx')
```

And the .csv files look like so:
[.csv files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeuvM.png)

I am getting this error from the command line and I am unsure what is going wrong, can anyone help?

```
ValueError: Cannot convert ['1', '82', '1', 'Mar 31', 'MIN', '@', 'CHW', 'L3-
5', 'CG', '3', '3', '2', '2', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 
'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.667', '.667', '1.000', '1.667', '8', '1.20', 
'0.092', '0.99', 'CF'] to Excel
```

Comment: I'll post this as a comment first.

But you might want to check at [I/o Tools from Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/io.html) 

With `read_csv()` and `to_excel` you might find an easiest way to convert such a simple CSV

Comment: @ThomasDussaut thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it with  `pandas.read_csv()` and `pandas.to_excel()`
happy coding